# Php Build an Array from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I currently collect data like this :

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM applicants";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo $row['id'].$row['name'].$row['surname'].$row['email'].$row['dob'];
    echo "<br />";
}
```

It outputs all the data in one line, like this

```
1maxpaynemax@hat.com24/07/1950
```

I want to build the data into a Array rather so it looks like this :

```
$fields = array(
        'id' => '21890',
        'name' => 'nick',
        'surname' => 'moppy',
        'email' => 'nick@moppy.com',
        'dob' => '11-01-1965',

    ),
```

Comment: You're half-way through it, just replace your array values with the proper variables and you're done. And actually, `$row` is already the original array you are looking to build.

Comment: $row is already an array

Comment: Pass MYSQL_ASSOC into mysql_fetch_array and that's what you're after isn't it in $row?

Comment: Do you need $fields array with only values for id, name, etc.. or whole table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use this way.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM applicants";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
   $res[] = $row;

 }
echo "<pre>"; print_r($res);   echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: no need to use that now as var_dump will do that work

Comment: @D4V1D It is not exactly the same. Its better.

Answer (score 1):

You **already** have your array:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM applicants";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    var_dump($row);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So I'm going to make an assumption here. That is that you only want `id`, `name`, `surname`, `email` and `dob`. If you want all the columns returned from the table and in the array, just return the `SELECT` to what it was.

```
$query = "SELECT id, name, surname, email, dob FROM applicants";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
    // $row is now what your example array looks like
}
```

So there are 2 differences, first, the specified columns from the table. If you're actually wanting all of the columns returned (back to using * for example), but don't want all of the columns returned in your array, this won't work (but you haven't said either way) but @b0s3 first example will.

Second, the addition of the `MYSQL_ASSOC` parameter. This tells PHP to return an array with only the column name indicies as opposed to them AND numeric keys which doubles up the number of items in the array.